# Can someone please explain why I'm getting infinite loop in this code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char name[20];
    FILE *fptr=fopen("Student1.txt","w");
    fputc('J',fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
   
    
    FILE *ptr=fopen("Student1.txt","r");
    char ch;
   // ch=fgetc(ptr);
    fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",ch);
        fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I have been getting an infinite loop when I run this code.

I'm stuck at this code for so long now.

Please try to help.

Comment: `ch` is never `EOF` here. If might be from `fgetc()` but not from `fscanf()`. (And with `fgetc()` you should use `int char;`). But here, the loop should be `while(fscanf(ptr, "%c", &ch) == 1) printf("%c", ch);` and remove the first `fscanf()`.

Comment: I would use `printf("%d %d\n",ch,EOF);` to get an idea what's happening.

Comment: i would try both the options.Thank you!

Comment: You can try both, but the code is rather different for each.

Comment: Typo in the first comment, sorry. With `fgetc()` you should use `int ch;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An infinite loop typically means that the loop condition `ch != EOF` remains true forever.  The only way you set `ch` is via the two calls to `fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);`.  `fscanf()` *returns* EOF when the end of a file is reached which is different than setting the (out) argument `ch`.  Here is how I would write it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fptr=fopen("Student1.txt","w");
    if(!fptr) {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fputc('J',fptr);
    fclose(fptr);

    FILE *ptr=fopen("Student1.txt","r");
    if(!ptr) {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(;;) {
        char ch;
        int r = fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);
        if(r == EOF)
            break;
        if(r != 1) {
            printf("fscanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%c",ch);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Consider refactoring the two `fopen()` calls into a single `FILE * fptr = fopen(..., "rw")` then truncate the file with `ftruncate(fileno(fptr), 0)`.

Comment: any simpler solution than this?

Comment: Allan Wind, can you tell me why you used the condition if(r!=1) and why you used **int** r to store value of **fscanf** ? and what does **return 1** do??

Comment: `fscanf()` returns the "the number of input items successfully matched and assigned", so this means, that `ch` is uninitialized unless r == 1.  `return 1` just quits your program, it's the same as `exit(1)` which means something went wrong.  As for `int r`, `fscanf()` returns an`int` and `r` is just a short variable name for for "return value".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fgetch()` and `fscanf()` have different interfaces.

- `fgetch()` returns an `int` value to designate all the possible character values (from 0 to 255) and also `EOF` (which is none of them, generally implemented as -1). `fgetch()` returns `EOF` to indicate the end of file condition (which is not a character, but merely a situation)
- `fscanf()` stores a representation of the `char` just read in the variable pointed to.  **But it will never store `EOF` in the variable** (indeed, it will store *nothing* at all, in the case of an end of file condition), as `EOF` doesn't represent a character, it is not worth storing it in a `char` variable.

`fscanf()` returns the number of format specifiers that it could satisfy, so in this case

```
    // ch=fgetc(ptr);
    fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",ch);
        fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);
    }
```

that will never happen (It will, in case you enter a `char` value that could be converted as a signed integer into the value `EOF` has, just try to enter the character value `0xff` (in case you can do that from the keyboard).  But that is completely incorrect, as the character stored in the variable would be a true character (that happens to convert to -1 when converted to an `int`) and it can happen in the middle of a file.  The infinite loop happens because on an end of file, nothing is stored on the `char` variable, and so `ch` never changes again, if it was not the *magic* character described above, it will never satisfy the condition to get out of the loop.

The actual behaviour of `fscanf()` is that it will return 1 for all the characters actually read, and 0, on satisfying the end of file condition.  A good working example would be:

```
    while (fscanf(ptr, "%c", &ch) == 1) {
        printf("%c",ch);
        fscanf(ptr,"%c",&ch);
    }
```